# is it possible to pass request.body via post request in django test client?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I have not found any way so far.

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.options
```

shows that options allows request.body via get request but cannot find any way to pass via post request. Any ideas, I have been looking for a few hours now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What data do you want to send in the test post request?

Answer (score 11):

Yes:

```
self.client.generic('POST', '/url', 'raw post data')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do:

```
request.body = b'{"first": "fred", "last": "dredd"}'
```

You should do it like this:

```
request._body = b'{"first": "fred", "last": "dredd"}'
```